# How to power a circuit of LEDs with maximum 5v

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm working on adding some LED's to some electric train engines that can have a variable power input up to 13V. I was hoping that under 5V, the power could go directly to the LED (with an inline resistor) for variable brightness, but limit the circuit to 5V as the input voltage increased beyond 5V so the maximum LED brightness could be achieved before maximum input voltage. I was thinking of using a 7805, but not sure how to get it to work below the dropout of ~7v. I'm fairly new to electronics, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Specifically what LEDs are you attempting to connect to your trains? (I get the idea that the power supply in the tracks varies.)

Comment: Just standard 5mm LEDs. I'll probably use different colors, but only 1 per train (so 1 per circuit).

Comment: \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ variety, then?

Comment: Yes, targeting 15mA across the LED for longevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: circuit]

I ended up building my own AMS1117 module with a diode rectifier. It achieves full brightness at the point the train starts moving. Perfect! Thanks for the tip on the 1117, @FakeMoustache!

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER EVER** connect a LED directly to a supply unless it is specifically designed for that. Almost all common LEDs are not.

**ALWAYS** use a series resistor.

If you make 20 mA flow at 13 V then at 5 V the LED will still work but at a lower brightness. For that 20 mA you need a 500 ohm resistor. 500 ohm resistors are hard to find so get some 560 ohm resistors (that's close enough) and use one resistor in series with one LED. Simple but works flawlessly.

Comment: I should have clarified. I have this variable brightness working already with an inline resistor. I was hoping to achieve maximum brightness at a lower voltage (5v?) then maintain it with a voltage regulator as the source voltage increased.

Comment: Indeed you should have mentioned that. A 7805 is indeed an option, easier still are ready made modules from ebay like http://www.ebay.nl/itm/AMS1117-1-2-5V-DC-Step-Down-Voltage-Regulator-Adaptateur-Convertor-Supply-Modul-/192033661535?var=&hash=item2cb619225f:m:miYk137Tt2ZgZXUcGZO84Tg  LEDs do not take that much current so a 7805 is a bit overkill and the AMS1117 on the module will drop less voltage when at 5 V input.

Comment: Or you could put many LEDs in series and feed all of them from for example 24 V using this module: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/172418818831?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT Similar to Andy's solution but low power.

Comment: I ended up building my own AMS1117 module to force myself to learn more. The modules you pointed to on eBay are pretty much what I built, but mine includes a diode rectifier because the trains are reversible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a constant current drive circuit that would work well on most LEDs down to below 5 volts. It involves an op-amp and a transistor and a couple of resistors. However, using one of these circuits per LED becomes hopelessly inefficient and so a better idea is to use a boost converter and wire the LEDs in series. If you have (say) 6 LEDs, the net forward voltage needed could be between 12 volts (standard red LED) and 20 odd volts (white LEDs).

Maybe something like this: -

[image]

The current can be controlled by raising the 2.49 ohm resistor. You can get it to work down to 4 volts by using a Sepic topology: -

[image]

As said earlier, you control LED current with \$R_{SENSE}\$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only talking about low-power LEDS for decoration, then a simple little circuit like the one below would approximate to your requirements.  The resistor values are intended to deliver about 5mA to a white LED, and may need adjusting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUzJjd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This looks promising. Am I understanding this correctly in that under 3.3v, the D2 is a dead end because it's an open circuit, so the current flows through D1 as a standard LED curcuit. But above 3.3v, D2 breaks down and allows the excess current to flow that way, acting like a parallel diode circuit?

Comment: Pretty much.  Up to about 5V supply, the voltage across the zener will be less than 3.3V, so it will do nothing.  Above 5V, the voltage at the zener will hit 3.3V, and any excess current through R2 will go through the zener, bypassing the LED.  This rather simple circuit will get rather warm at 13V, and isn't really suitable for handling any larger currents.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Fake's Moustache's answer. If you use a 5v led at higher voltage with resistor at higher voltage this decreases the life span of the LED. And there is a safe upper limit (with any resistor) before the led is damaged

Answer (score 0):

The company, Evans Designs, makes LED lights for electric trains. They aren't all that expensive, either, and come with necessary circuitry.

1. Let's assume the current is \$I_{led}=20\:\textrm{mA}\$ for now, but keep open the idea of more current if needed. (You mentioned in a later comment that \$I_{led}=15\:\textrm{mA}\$.)
2. Your track voltage (I gather) can get to over \$13\:\textrm{V}\$. But I think some trains operate on AC and some on DC. If this is an AC track, you may want to include a bridge rectifier and a following capacitor (optionally) as the first part of the circuit. I'll assume DC, for now.

To a first approximation, common \$5\:\textrm{mm}\$ LEDs should be operated with a constant current and not a constant voltage. Clearly, you know that. But given the wider dynamic range of your source voltage, a special circuit to provide a constant current would help.

If you want to try doing this with just one (or two) BJT(s), you could attempt either of the following two choices at very low cost.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYRaLw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Current for the LED in the left-hand side circuit comes through \$R_2\$, with \$Q_1\$ diverting (it's a shunt regulator) any extra current through its collector. \$R_2=\frac{V_{BE_1}}{I_{led}}\$. (You can assume that \$V_{BE_1}\approx 760-800\:\textrm{mV}\$ for a small signal device.) And \$R_1=\frac{V_{min}-V_{led}-V_{BE_1}}{1.5\cdot I_{led}}\$, where \$V_{min}\$ is your minimum DC operating voltage and \$V_{led}\$ is, of course, your LED's operating voltage.

The serious problem for this circuit is that \$R_1\$ will dissipate terrible amounts of power when operating at the higher voltages. Perhaps a watt, or more, as it has to drop all that extra voltage.

The right hand circuit attempts to deal with that problem. In this case, \$Q_3\$ will be dissipating the excess power at higher voltages. But since the current is fixed (roughly) across the input voltage ranges, the power isn't terrible. Perhaps \$200\:\textrm{mW}\$ when talking about \$I_{led}=20\:\textrm{mA}\$. But keep in mind that this goes linearly upwards with increasing LED current and linearly downward when talking about less LED current. So just be aware of that.

In this right-hand circuit, \$Q_3\$ won't be operated in saturation. With \$V_{BE_2}\approx 680\:\textrm{mV}\$ and \$V_{led}\le 3.2\:\textrm{V}\$, \$V_{CE_3}\$ should be enough to stay out of saturation. However, if the LED voltage is more, then it's possible that \$Q_3\$ might go a little into saturation. So I'd recommend assuming \$\beta_3\approx 50\$ for purposes of setting \$R_4\$. So, \$R_4=\beta_3\cdot\frac{V_{min}-V_{BE_2}-V_{BE_3}}{I_{led}}\$ to supply needed base current for \$Q_3\$ (plus a little, given that \$\beta_3\$ is taken as a relatively low value.) Without \$Q_2\$ and \$R_3\$ present, there'd be no current control. But with \$R_3=\frac{V_{BE_2}}{I_{led}}\$, the voltage developed across \$R_3\$ will begin to turn on \$Q_2\$, which will shunt (sink) base current away from \$Q_3\$ when the LED current rises more than desired.

The result of all this on the right-hand circuit is that there isn't so much of a waste of power. It's better, in short, than the left-hand circuit when considering dissipation. But it costs you some complexity. Still, it's small and easy enough that you can pack it into heat-shrink tubing and be done with it. It should work fine.

---

My recommendation, of course, is the right-hand circuit. Even with higher desired LED currents, you can probably get away with a small signal BJT. But I'd recommend testing that idea, too. It's a *maybe* and not a *for-sure*. One thing I worry about here is that there is no temperature compensation at all and if \$Q_3\$ heats up a lot and passes that heat along to \$Q_2\$, then base-emitter junction voltage of \$Q_2\$ drops significantly and this will reduce the LED current. But I think it may be fine for \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ and may be still somewhat less "ok" at somewhat higher currents.

NOTE: [If you found a problem with heating in the right-hand circuit (unlikely with \$I_{led}=15\:\textrm{mA}\$), I might parallel two small signal BJTs as \$Q_3\$ and, if being really picky, might only connect the collectors and bases together, but not connect the emitters directly -- instead using a small series resistor in each emitter leg before connecting them together. In this picky case, I'd select these two emitter resistors to drop about \$200\:\textrm{mV}\$, so with \$I_{led}=15\:\textrm{mA}\$ these would probably be \$12-15\:\Omega\$ resistor values.]

I get my BJTs at about 3 for a penny. My resistors cost me as much, too. So that's about two cents for the right-hand circuit, plus labor, solder, shrink-wrap, and the LED of course. In short, the electronics bits are essentially free and they aren't boutique parts and never will be. So it's good in that sense, as well.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. The Evans Designs lights claim to require 7+ voltage in, so that won't work for me, but they make lots of cool stuff I will use. Running a DC sweep on the right-hand circuit only results in exactly the input DC voltage. The left side stayed significantly lower than 3V and was a linear increase, so it doesn't maintain max brightness across the full input range. I ended up going with an AMS1117 circuit that works really well.

Comment: @695Multimedia Sounds great, then. The overhead in my right hand circuit requires a minimum overhead of about 1.5 V more than the LED requires. The AMS1117 has a minimum of 1.0 V. The main thing for me is the boutique nature of using the AMS1117. I prefer (just me) to use parts that have been around for decades and will continue to be for decades more (and available from lots of suppliers.) I'm glad that worked out so well for you, though!! Excellent.